# Facebook SDK iOS Login View still pops up after relaunching app

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I've got it all working, I've even posted to Facebook already.  I was using the Xcode Simulator the first time and it asked for user authentication, I entered my user info, then it gave me a second Facebook dialog window saying it was authorized and had to press OKAY button.  This takes me to my app.

What bugs me is that every time I run the app, it doesn't ask me for my credentials again, but it does pop-up a Facebook dialog window saying I've logged in fine, and I have to press the OKAY button in the bottom right.

Is there anyway to avoid this, cause still be a pain for my users every time?

Answer (score 1):

u have been asking for permission for accessing the data everytime in facebook

to avoid this ask only one time for permission by setting the if loop with permission with bool ...

i think u understand

Comment: ok you mean add this:if (![facebook isSessionValid]) {
  [facebook authorize:permissions delegate:self];
 } // but permissions is undeclared

Comment: yes.u r right.permission is the array which contains the related tags to specify to user ,we want to access the area in that tags.if u dont have anything like that then specify with permission array as with nil.even u can access the public visibily properties of user as usual .enjoy